# Why am I getting a "InvaladCastExeption Was Unhandled" Error?

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, runtime-error, vb.net-2010

```
Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
    Dim CaseCompareItem As String = ListBox.SelectedValue
    Select Case CaseCompareItem

        Case "MyText" Or "NotText"
            MsgBox("YAY!!! IT WORKED!!!!!")
    End Select
End Sub
```

(I shortened the code quite a bit: I didn't want to have 12 different cases that are unnecessary.)

**All I get is a runtime error.** The error reads:

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled   Message=Conversion from
>   string "Canoe (Not In Service) 1MP" to type 'Long' is not valid.
>   Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToLong(String
>   Value)
>          at Money_Money.ChapterTwo.MakeArmyShipButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\Matthew's\My
>   Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Money Money\Money
>   Money\ChapterTwo.vb:line 166
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[]
>   commandLine)
>          at Money_Money.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException: System.FormatException
>          Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
>          Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic
>          StackTrace:
>               at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDecimal(String
>   Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
>               at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToLong(String
>   Value)
>          InnerException:

Why is this happening???

Comment: I don't think you're showing the code that's actually crashing.  Can you paste in `MakeArmyShipButton_Click`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Or` in a `Case` statement implies an integral type which will cause the conversion to `Long` to throw an exception.  Replace it with a ','.

These kinds of mistakes are common with those that refuse to turn Option Strict On, which will flag them when they're written.

You will probably find more success using the `SelectedItem` property, instead of the `SelectedValue` property, and also you should  check if the object is nothing before accessing it's value:

```
    If Not ListBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        Dim CaseCompareItem As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        Select Case CaseCompareItem

            Case "MyText", "NotText"
                MsgBox("YAY!!! IT WORKED!!!!!")
        End Select
    End If
```